# Ansible role analysis with Checkov - facts evaluation?

Tags: ansible, static-analysis, checkov

I wanted to run a Checkov analysis on Ansible roles I'm developping.
Checkov reports some errors that shouldn't be reported if you take into account the value of the facts.

Here is a simple example on a simplified playbook:

```
- name: Test checkov
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Set BASE_URL
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        BASE_URL: "https://localhost:1234/myportal"

    - name: call myportal
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: "{{ BASE_URL }}/CsrfGuardServlet"
        method: POST
        status_code: 200
        return_content: true
        headers:
          FETCH-CSRF-TOKEN: 1
        body_format: form-urlencoded
        body:
          _action: submit
      register: csrf_response
      no_log: true
```

Checkov returns the following error:

```
$> checkov -f checkov_test.yaml  --quiet --evaluate-variables True 
ansible scan results:

Passed checks: 1, Failed checks: 1, Skipped checks: 0

Check: CKV2_ANSIBLE_1: "Ensure that HTTPS url is used with uri"
 FAILED for resource: tasks.ansible.builtin.uri.call myportal
 File: /checkov_test.yaml:9-22

                9  |     - name: call myportal
                10 |       ansible.builtin.uri:
                11 |         url: "{{ BASE_URL }}/CsrfGuardServlet"
                12 |         method: POST
                13 |         status_code: 200
                14 |         return_content: true
                15 |         headers:
                16 |           FETCH-CSRF-TOKEN: 1
                17 |         body_format: form-urlencoded
                18 |         body:
                19 |           _action: submit
                20 |       register: csrf_response
```

Though clearly the url uses HTTPS.

Is there a way to tell checkov to take into account declared facts? (whether through ansible.builtin.set_fact or with vars - as this leads to the same error).

Comment: I suspect the problem is that facts are dynamic values: they can vary depending on the runtime environment. It's difficult for a static analyzer to *guarantee* what the value will be without actually executing the playbook. In your position I would simply disable that particular check, if possible.